# Apache mina vs Simple NIO for transferring large files

Tags: apache-mina

I am trying to figure out options for transferring large files over network.

1. So, I created a simple TCP server/ client to transfer around 10G of file.
2. Then I replaced FileStreams and sockets with NIO apis and found significant performance improvements due to less IO overhead.

Now I have learned that Apache Mina is a framework based on NIO which is used for rapidly developing client server applications.

My questions are , apart from a flexibility provided by Mina to create client/server apps - 
1. Does Mina provide anything special over NIO to improve the performance ?
2. If yes, where can I find benchmarks which supports this arguement ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Mina is using NIO, so I believe both will provide you the same performances.